# Where can I find package 'libpng12.so.0'?

Tags: apt, vmware, shared-library

I have been using `vmware horizon client` on Ubuntu 16.04 but yesterday upgraded to 16.10(I regret that now :( ) since then vmware client is throwing the below error:

```
/usr/lib/vmware/view/bin/vmware-view: error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I googled the same error and found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480764/linux-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-s) and tried the answer 2(as answer 1 seemed to be more on why we get this error) mentioned there
but I am still getting the same error.

I am thinking of reinstalling 16.04 LTS but just wanted to try my luck here..

Any help?

Comment: look at my comment here, Tested on my 16.10 64 bit install, no issues http://askubuntu.com/questions/838949/ubuntu-16-10-teamvieweri386-depends-on-libpng12-0#comment1283182_838949

Comment: Try to check if it is there:
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0

Comment: Try `sudo apt install libpng12-0`

Comment: @GrannySez I tried your suggestion but I am getting this error: `E: Package 'libpng12-0' has no installation candidate`

Comment: @RohittVashishtha no it is available here `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

Comment: @javanoob. It seems the package libpng12-0 is only available up to (and including) ubuntu 16.04, so if you are on 16.10 or later it is not available. In response to your issue about no installation candidate see a possible solution at [https://askubuntu.com/questions/840257/e-package-libpng12-0-has-no-installation-candidate-ubuntu-16-10-gnome/840268](https://askubuntu.com/questions/840257/e-package-libpng12-0-has-no-installation-candidate-ubuntu-16-10-gnome/840268)

Comment: @DavidFoerster How is this duplicate? The question you tagged was asked 3 days after this one. How could anyone expect that :)

Comment: Age is irrelevant for duplication flags. What matters is that the (underlying) issue is the same or at least has the same solution(s) and that the linked question has "better" answers.

Answer (score 4):

It seems VMware actually ships libpng12.so.0 with the client. You can link to it with this command:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libpng12.so.0/libpng12.so.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0
```

Comment: Which vmware product?

Comment: There is no `lib` directory inside `/usr/lib/vmware/`

Comment: This works for me `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 /usr/lib/vmware/libpng12.so.0`

Comment: Thanks !
Solved my problem for VMWare Horizon Client 4.6.0 on a Ubuntu 16.04 distro

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu 17.04 you can create these two symbolic links as a workaround.

```
sudo ln -s libudev.so /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0
sudo ln -s libpng16.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0
```

Comment: where do you put these symlinks?

Comment: This doesn’t really help if libpng12 is expected: `libpng12.so.0: version 'PNG12_0' not found`

Answer (score 2):

I tried linking the VMware provided libpng12.so.0 file and still got the lib dependency issue. Installing the DEB files directly did resolve it though:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libpng12-0/download
http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/i386/libpng12-0/download

Comment: Could you add how to install them? Did you run `sudo apt install -f` afterwards?