# E: Package 'libpng12-0' has no installation candidate [ubuntu 16.10 Gnome]

Tags: dependencies, wps-office, libpng

I tried to install WPS Office on my laptop (ubuntu 16.10 Gnome, 64 bit) with  Gdebi installer but it said

```
Dependency is not satisfiable: libpng12-0
```

Then I tried to open this library as follows

```
sudo apt-get install libpng12-0
```

But I encountered an error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libpng12-0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libpng12-0' has no installation candidate
```

Can anyone help? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can download the `libpng12-0` package from here:

- http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/i386/libpng12-0/download for i386 architecture and
- http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libpng12-0/download for amd64.

I had the same dependency problem. But downloading and installing fix edthe error. Ubuntu 16.10 killed these libs jeje.

Comment: wow. it worked. thanks a lot. It took me the whole day!

Comment: following the instruction at the link to add the mirror to your sources worked for me

Comment: Running Xubuntu 17.10. This solution didn't work for me. After installing libpng12-0 this way, the TeamViewer install (what I'm really trying to install) still thinks libpng12-0 is not installed. Do I need to update a database somewhere?

Comment: This answer doesn't set up correct package pinning. You need to do this (unfortunately can't post as an answer cause lack of rep): Package: *
Pin: release n=xenial
Pin-Priority: -10

Package: libpng12-0
Pin: release n=xenial
Pin-Priority: 500

Comment: deadlink, please fix

Answer (score 17):

Downloading and manually installing a package is not the recommended way of doing things in ubuntu, it is strongly suggested to use a package manager like aptitude or synaptic to download and install packages.

To do it in the command line first you have to add a repository.  This involves modifying /etc/apt/sources.list so you must create a backup

Open a Terminal window

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

At the top of the list add

```
#### BACKUP for /etc/apt/sources.list created <insert date here>
```

press ctrl+o to save the file to a new location.  I have a folder in my home directory for backups, but you can put it anywhere you will remember that it exists.  For my backup folder I saved it as /home/USERNAME/os_file_backups/backup_03-06-17_apt-sources.list
hit enter to save, it will ask you if you want to save it with a different name press y to save the file and then ctrl-x to exit nano

once again go back to sources.list

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

at the bottom of the file add

```
#### Manually Added sources
## source for libpng12-0 package
deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/ xenial main
```

^note for above, mirrors.kernel.org is one of many mirrors that can be used.  You can replace `mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu` with any of the mirrors listed at http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libpng12-0/download that you wish to use

press ctrl+x and hit yes to save the file

now to update the package list

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and install the package

```
sudo apt-get install libpng12-0
```

shazam you have added libpng-12-0 using apt so you will get updated packages whenever you run apt-get upgrade

Comment: This solution doesn't work in Xubuntu 17.10. The mirror is not recognized.

Comment: Is there a solution available for Ubuntu 17.10?

Comment: @M.AtifRiaz This issue was part of a problem I was having with Ubuntu 17.10. [I posted a more generalized question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1005643/169237) and included what seems to be a solution to the libpng issue. Maybe that will help?

Comment: For me on Ubuntu 17.10 installing wps-office was successful after installing `libpng` through `sudo apt-get install libpng-dev` command

Comment: After loads of faffing about on Xubuntu Bionic This one worked for me! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This also happen when you try to install incompatible package with your distro (like install `trusty` .dep package on `bionic`).