# 32bit programme on 64bit machine

Tags: architecture

I have upgraded from 16.04 to 16.10. I have reinstalled HMRC.'s Basic PAYE. tools. On starting it from the command line, it fails citing the absence of libpng12.so.0 as the reason. I assumed that libpng12-0:i386 had been replaced by libpng15-15:i386 but it does not like this. How can I install libpng12-0:i386 in ubuntu16.10

Comment: The problem is dependencies in 16.10, not the architecture.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to find a version of the tool that is supported on 16.10. Else check this: [E: Package 'libpng12-0' has no installation candidate [ubuntu 16.10 Gnome]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/840257/e-package-libpng12-0-has-no-installation-candidate-ubuntu-16-10-gnome/840268) to download the library from http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/i386/libpng12-0/download

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install libpng12-0:i386`

This type of command specifies to install the mentionned package (here libpng12-0) for a 32-bit architecture.  This is related to multi-arch, allowing you to install packages for Debian related OS, like Ubuntu;  For more info, see for instance: [Debian multi-arch HOWTO](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this. I started the programme from the command line. When it failed it gave me the name of the missing library file dependency. I installed synaptic and looked in the "architecture" for the nearest match. I then reinstalled the 64bit version and installed the 32bit version to make sure there were no conflicts. After about 6 missing library files it gave up and ran perfectly !