# r-base-core : Depends: libpng12-0 failure

Tags: apt, package-management

I cant install R-base-core because libpng12-0 cannot be installed. trying to install just libpng12-0 i get

```
Package 'libpng12-0' has no installation candidate
```

I have seen a number of posts about adding different repos, but all of them either did nothing or gave `Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default`

Here is the full failure:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base-core : Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not installable
               Recommends: r-recommended but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: r-base-dev but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: r-doc-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

calling uname -a gives
`4.13.0-16-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 11 18:35:14 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

running this command:
`cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

```
#

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 17.10 _Artful Aardvark_ - Release amd64 (20171017.1)]/ artful main restricted

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 17.10 _Artful Aardvark_ - Release amd64 (20171017.1)]/ artful main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu artful partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu artful partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security multiverse
deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/
deb https://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/
# deb-src https://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/
```

I spent quite a bit of time trying to install R tonight.

Answer (score 1):

You should download the repository of R for your version of ubuntu, i.e. Artful and not xenial.
First try to download and install libpng12-0 as in [E: Package 'libpng12-0' has no installation candidate [ubuntu 16.10 Gnome]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/840257/e-package-libpng12-0-has-no-installation-candidate-ubuntu-16-10-gnome/840268).

Then, the r-base-core of that version should be based on libreadline6, which is not available anymore. Thus, download the version for ubuntu artful and remove the following lines from `sources.list`

```
deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/
deb https://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/
# deb-src https://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/
```