# Cannot install WPS Office

Tags: dependencies, wps-office

I'm using Ubuntu GNOME 16.10 and was trying to install WPS Office. I tried to install using software centre But it wasn't installing without giving any error logs. Then I opened it with Gdebi installer. Here is what I saw.

[image: shows erorr]

I have already trying enabling multiverse repositories.

**Edit:**
I have downloaded the amd64 package from the WPS official site, but even now installing through terminal I still get the missing dependencies error.

Comment: Have tried using the `.deb` files from [here](http://wps-community.org/downloads) ? To install use `sudo dpkg -i package_name`

Comment: @George yes i have tried, still in the terminal, it shows....

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wps-office:
 wps-office depends on libpng12-0; however:
  Package libpng12-0 is not installed.

Comment: do this `sudo apt -f install && sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade` then if all goes well try installing again.

Comment: the problem is that [`libpng12-0`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libpng12%2D0) is only present in the repositories until Ubuntu 16.04 LTS! - i don't know why and can't tell you how, but you will need `libpng12-0` to install WPS Office.

Comment: @DJCrashdummy Oh thx that solved the problem.

Comment: Check the upvoted answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/838949/ubuntu-16-10-teamvieweri386-depends-on-libpng12-0 (Different software but the same dependency)

Comment: Or you can download the xenial version directly here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libpng12-0 (install it before attempting to install WPS again. WPS should be updated ASAP to avoid this problem in 16.10.

Comment: Thank you all my problem is solved. I had to download _libpng12-0_ packge and then it installed and now it runs flawlessly. On a different note, it haven't been long since i have installed ubuntu 16.10 and it turns out it has many dependency bugs. @CelticWarrior

Comment: @AlanJameson In this case it's the other way around. WPS needs to be updated in order to either no longer depend on a deprecated library or package it together if unavoidable. It's not the new OS that has to run old software, it's the software that needs to be updated to run in the new OS. This is true for all OSes and in particular the closed source ones.

Comment: @AlanJameson, I have found another solution. Please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [WPS Office for Linux](http://wps-community.org/downloads) up to version 10.1.0.5672~a21 ("Alpha21[2016-06-24]") - still depends on a deprecated library since Ubuntu 16.10, mentioned in the error message.

**Workaround**

[Download](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libpng12-0) and install the `libpng12-0` version still available for Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial) before installing WPS Office for Linux.

Comment: up to version 10.1.0.5707_a21

Comment: The new version has the same dependency to `libpng12`. -- The solution is also described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966750/how-to-install-wps-office-on-ubuntu-17-10)

Answer (score 1):

**I was having same problem found solution:**

Download `libpng12-0` package from [here](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/libpng12-0/download)

Install package using:

```
sudo dpkg -i libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u3_amd64.deb
```

Now install WPS office downloaded form [here](http://wps-community.org/downloads) using:

```
sudo dpkg -i wps-office_10.1.0.5672~a21_amd64.deb
```

I have tried this on `Ubuntu 16.10` and it's working fine.

Comment: I have already downloaded the package.  Its the same package i tried to install.

Comment: This is the standard procedure the user already tried. It has a dependency problem and this doesn't answer that problem.

Comment: @CelticWarrior, I have edited the answer and now it solves dependency problem.