# How to install wps-office on ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: 17.10

> ```
> android@android:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i wps-office_10.1.0.5707_a21_amd64.deb
> ```

```
[sudo] password for android: 
Selecting previously unselected package wps-office.
(Reading database ... 134330 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack wps-office_10.1.0.5707_a21_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking wps-office (10.1.0.5707~a21) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wps-office:
 wps-office depends on libpng12-0; however:
  Package libpng12-0 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package wps-office (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.8-1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 wps-office
android@android:~/Downloads$ sudo apt install libpng16-16
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libpng16-16 is already the newest version (1.6.34-1).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wps-office : Depends: libpng12-0 but it is not installable
              Recommends: ttf-mscorefonts-installer but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

> ```
> android@android:~/Downloads$ sudo apt install -f
> ```

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  wps-office
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 386 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 136822 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing wps-office (10.1.0.5707~a21) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.8-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-1) ...
```

> ```
> android@android:~/Downloads$ sudo apt install libpng16-16
> ```

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libpng16-16 is already the newest version (1.6.34-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

> ```
> android@android:~/Downloads$ apt search libpng12-0
> ```

```
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
```

> ```
> android@android:~/Downloads$
> ```

Comment: Contact the maintainer of wps-office and file a bug report.

Comment: Ubuntu uses `libpng16-16` instead of `libpng12`. Contact the maintainer of wps-office to use a most recent version of the library and/or change the dependency rules in the `.deb` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error mentions that `wps` requires `libpng12-0`, a package that is not installable in your machine. There are [Ubuntu packages for `libpng12-0`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libpng12-0) for trusty (14.04LTS) and xenial (16.04LTS), but not for 17.10.  You must ask to the software manufacturer (i.e. WPS) to update the program and/or the installer to use the most recent `libpng16-16`.

Tools such as `aptitude` can find a solution, for instance, to downgrade the library, only if you have repositories configured in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` with the old versions.

---

As a workaround, you may try to download and install the `.deb` package for Xenial [from the Ubuntu web page](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libpng12-0/download) before installing wps.

1. Installing `libpng12`

   ```
   $ wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
   $ sudo dpkg -i libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
   ```
2. Installing `wps`

   ```
   $ wget http://kdl1.cache.wps.com/ksodl/download/linux/a21//wps-office_10.1.0.5707~a21_amd64.deb
   $ sudo dpkg -i wps-office_10.1.0.5707~a21_amd64.deb
   ```
3. Running `wps` (in a X or Desktop)

   ```
   $ wps
   ```

> **NOTE:** Installing packages from older distributions may break your `apt` installation system.

---

**Is it safe to install the `libpng12` package from Xenial (16.04LTS) ?**

Using packages from older distributions can be dangerous. It may break the `apt` installation system because older packages may introduce dependencies to non-existing packages or replace packages that the new versions require. Try to use packages and repositories for the Ubuntu version you are using, i.e., the official Ubuntu repositories and well-known PPA repositories (that test their packages).

To check if the installation of `libpng12` can break the `apt`, I checked [the package information](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libpng12-0).

- The `libpng12` depends on `libc6 (>= 2.14)` and `zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)` that are included in the recent Ubuntu versions.

  ```
  $ apt-cache policy libc6     # gives me 2.24-9ubuntu2.2
  $ apt-cache policy zlib1g    # gives me 1.2.11dfsg-0ubuntu1
  ```
- Note that no other Ubuntu package requires a recent version of `libpng12` because it is not included in the repository. The most recent programs depends on  `libpng16-16` and both libraries can coexist.
- I think that it is very unlikely that this package breaks the `apt`.

Do not try to install a package of an older distribution if you are not sure of what you are doing.

Comment: This is what I was also talking about in your other question - https://askubuntu.com/questions/966757/libpng12-needed-for-17-10 . Downgrading in the way you suggest is likely to cause conflicts with all those packages and result in a broken system. Far better to compile libpng12

Comment: I suppose if we do `sudo apt-mark hold libpng12-0:amd64`, will help to prevent to update or future conflicts with this package. (I may be wrong and this can be useless. I'm not an expert.)