# Libpng12 needed for 17.10

Tags: 17.10, libpng

Blackmagic Design's Resolve video editor, V14.0.1, requires libpng1**2**. Unfortunately, only libpng1**6** is provided with the new 17.10 release.

Is there a way to revert to libpng12 under 17.10? If so, how do I get libpng12 - synaptic doesn't list it when I search for it.

Comment: Contact Blackmagic and file a bug report. https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/support/

Comment: instead of installing obsolete packages to the system, they can also be placed adjacent to closed source binaries that depend on the without bundling them. Use `ldd ./path/to/<program>` to show the libraries the given binary will try to load. Compile or download the obsolete libraries either adjacent to the binary or manipulate envron LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include them. Beware, any software not distributed by your maintainer's package repository is not going to get security updates from thier security team; you're going to have to manually update the library yourself, four times a day is ideal :)

Answer (score 18):

There are [Ubuntu packages for `libpng12-0`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libpng12-0) for trusty (14.04LTS) and xenial (16.04LTS), but not for 17.10.  You must ask to the software manufacturer (i.e. Blackmagic Design) to update the program and/or the installer to use the most recent `libpng16-16`.

---

As a workaround, you may download and install the `.deb` package for Xenial [from the Ubuntu web page](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libpng12-0/download) before installing the Blackmagic Design's Resolve video editor.

- Installing `libpng12`

  ```
  $ wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
  $ sudo dpkg -i libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
  ```

> **NOTE:** Installing packages from older distributions may break your `apt` installation system.

---

**Is it safe to install the `libpng12` package from Xenial (16.04LTS) ?**

Using packages from older distributions can be dangerous. It may break the `apt` installation system because older packages may introduce dependencies to non-existing packages or replace packages that the new versions require. Try to use packages and repositories for the Ubuntu version you are using, i.e., the official Ubuntu repositories and well-known PPA repositories (that test their packages).

To check if the installation of `libpng12` can break the `apt`, I checked [the package information](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libpng12-0).

- The `libpng12` depends on `libc6 (>= 2.14)` and `zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)` that are included in the recent Ubuntu versions.

  ```
  $ apt-cache policy libc6     # gives me 2.24-9ubuntu2.2
  $ apt-cache policy zlib1g    # gives me 1.2.11dfsg-0ubuntu1
  ```
- Note that no other Ubuntu package requires a recent version of `libpng12` because it is not included in the repository. The most recent programs depends on  `libpng16-16` and both libraries can coexist.
- I think that it is very unlikely that this package breaks the `apt`.

Do not try to install a package of an older distribution if you are not sure of what you are doing.

Comment: You are sort of on the right track and this may work for simple packages. Mixing packages from different repositories is likely , however, to result in a broken system due to conflicting dependencies and the probability of a broken system increases with the number and complexity of the packages in question. Furthermore, installing via dpkg will only last until the next `sudo apt upgrade`, you would have to put the imported package on hold. Better off compiling libping12 and installing it in say /usr/local .

Comment: I agree, this solution does not work with all the packages you may need -- In concrete, I tried this in a recently installed Ubuntu 17.04 that had the `libpng16-16` package before installing `libpng12` for answering this question. Both libraries resulted installed. I did an `apt-get upgrade` at the end. -- Right now, I think the rules in the repository does not consider `libpng16` as a recent version of `libpng12`. In turn, `libpng12` only depends on libc6 (>= 2.14)  and zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4). -- I think this solution for `libpng12` may be safe for using `apt-get update`.

Comment: There are lots of changes between 16.04 and 17.10 and mixing packages from repositories is one of the many ways to break Ubuntu or more specifically apt.

Comment: Do you think that installing a package that only depends on `libc6` and `xzlib1g` (that exists in 17.x), which is independent of the included `libpng` library, and which no other package depend on it,  can break the `apt`? -- I think that programs such as WPS and the Resolve video editor depends on the (old) `libpng12` and they will not result hold. Recent Ubuntu programs does not depend on `libpng12` but `libpng16-16`. These apps will not be hold neither. -- For this concrete case, I think this solution is safe.

Comment: I am merely point out the inherent dangers of mixing packages from repositories. Not only do I think this can cause problems, but it certainly did when you gave the same advice on a different question. At best this is a temporary work around. Compiling from source is certainly safer. And the long term solution is to file a bug report to the package maintainer , none of which was mentioned in your answer (risks, breaking apt, the option to compile, nor the advice to file a bug report).

Comment: In this case, it will indeed not break Apt. However, another issue is that if an updated version of `libpng12` is uploaded to the 16.04 repositories, you will not automatically get this update, which is a concern especially if it is security-related. This can be fixed by adding the 16.04 repositories to your sources list and using apt-pinning so they are used only for `libpng12` (assigning priority < 100 to all other packages).

Comment: @fkraiem could you write an answer were you explain this in further detail? Sounds like one of the most solid solution, for this problem.

Comment: @Fleuv I, and probably others as well, have already discussed apt-pinning elsewhere, for example [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170079/update-single-package-from-ubuntu-utopic-unicorn-when-running-trusty-tahr/170100#170100).

Comment: Installing libpng12 did not break apt on 18.04.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using the binary package, you may compile `libpng`.

- If you have the source code of the program you wanna install, you can use the original source code. After installing the library, you can use it to configure and compile other applications.
- If you do not have the source code of the program but only a `.deb` installer, e.g., if the program is a commercial product, you must install a package to avoid errors during the installation. You can create the package from source code using instructions below.

---

**Compiling libpng from the official source code**

Note that [old libpng v1.2.x may have a lot of vulnerabilities](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html). It is recommended to use the most recent 1.2.x version from [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/files/libpng12) or [github](https://github.com/glennrp/libpng/releases). This is for the v.1.2.59 version.

1. Install the packages to compile software (if they are not installed)

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install build-essential
   ```
2. Obtain and extract the source code

   ```
   $ wget https://github.com/glennrp/libpng/archive/v1.2.59.tar.gz
   $ tar xvfz v1.2.59.tar.gz
   ```
3. Compile and install the library

   ```
   $ cd libpng-1.2.59/
   $ ./configure
   $ make check
   $ sudo make install
   ```

> **NOTE:** Installing the library will not set the dependency to `libpng12` as met in `apt`. You must use a `.deb` package to install it and support the installation of other `.deb` files that depend on it. To create the corresponding `.deb`package, you can use the following instructions.

---

**Using the source code of the Ubuntu package**

the `libpng12-0` package corresponds to `libpng 1.2.54`. Ubuntu has a customized version they named [`1.2.54-1ubuntu1`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libpng12-0).

1. Install the packages to compile software and create Ubuntu packages (if they are not installed)

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install build-essential fakeroot dpkg-dev devscripts
   ```
2. Download source code files using the `.dsc` file from the page

   ```
   $ dget -d http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.dsc
   ```
3. Extract the source code applying the patched provided by Ubuntu

   ```
   $ dpkg-source -x libpng_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.dsc
   ```
4. Check the dependencies for the package

   ```
   $ cd libpng-1.2.54/
   $ dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b
   ```

   It shows unmet build dependencies. In my case...

   ```
    :
   dpkg-checkbuilddeps: error: Unmet build dependencies: debhelper (>= 8.1.3) libtool automake autoconf zlib1g-dev
   ```
5. Install the dependencies

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install debhelper libtool automake autoconf zlib1g-dev
   ```
6. Compile

   ```
   $ fakeroot debian/rules binary
   ```

   The resulting packages will be located in the parent folder

   ```
   ../libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
   ../libpng12-dev_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
   ../libpng3_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
   ```
7. Use the resulting package

   ```
   $ cd ..
   $ sudo dpkg -i libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
   ```

> **NOTE:** Compiling and installing packages for old distributions is as dangerous as [using binary packages for old distributions](https://askubuntu.com/a/966763/727993). The described compilation process for the `libpng12` package uses only packages in the Ubuntu 17.x repositories and does not result in errors.  I think that using the resulting package will not break the `apt`.

Answer (score 1):

This source worked for me on Ubuntu 18:

```
sudo echo 'deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe' \ > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/extra.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install libpng12-0
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/extra.list
```

Found it [here](https://tutorialforlinux.com/2018/04/22/how-to-install-required-packages-for-canon-legacy-driver-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic/) while trying to install printer drivers and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

IMO you are safer compiling from source than you are using old packages from old repositories.

Best advice I can give you is to file a bug report with blackmagic, they need to update their dependencies.

https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/support/

To compile, go to the relevant ubuntu package to identify the package and upstream source

https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libpng12-0

So you want "libpng_1.2.54.orig.tar.xz"

https://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/files/libpng12/older-releases/1.2.54/

download, extract, compile, install (starting after download and extracting the tar ball).

```
cd libpng-1.2.54
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install
```

To remove again (if needed)

```
#run within libpng-1.2.54 directory
sudo make uninstall
```

I understand it seems like a few extra steps, but it is trivial to download and compile in this way and there is no risk of breaking apt.

Comment: If you compile the original source code and do the `make install`, the `.deb` installer will not find the dependency to `libpng-12` as met. The installer will fail. -- This solution will work if you can get access to the source code or other type of installer for the software. -- If you cannot get the source code, you may compile the sources for the Ubuntu package and install the resulting file before installing the software you want.

Comment: I've given up the idea. It's really just a band-aid for a program from a vendor who's ...um... somewhat difficult to work with. It's a pity, as the product has a lot going for it. Oh well... moving on...