# Installing WPS office in 17.10

Tags: software-installation, wps-office

I'm using WPS on my Windows network and would like to use it on my Ubuntu 17.10 computer.  I'm not very conversant in Linux.  Anybody have a suggestion?

Comment: http://wps-community.org/download.html

Comment: If you try to install the `.deb` file downloaded from their website (linked in the comment above), you'll likely see some error(s). Then follow this Q&A:  [How to install wps-office on ubuntu 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966750/how-to-install-wps-office-on-ubuntu-17-10)

Comment: I've seen that but it is for the android version.

Comment: @fmw What do you mean? What's "*for the android version*"? The link lists `.deb` packages. It's **very** unlikely those are for android.